# Wix: Set permission of a folder within the installfolder using permissionEx

Tags: permissions, wix, directory, custom-action

I'm creating an installer for an ASP.NET MVC web app using Wix, and I need to set a write permissions for the IIS_WPG on a particular folder in the site. I found an example (I think, still haven't got it working) of how to do this with cacls.exe:

```
<CustomAction Id="PermissionAppData" Directory="TARGETDIR" 
  ExeCommand="&quot;[SystemFolder]cacls.exe&quot; 
  &quot;[INSTALLDIR]\Content\uploads&quot; 
  /T /E /G IIS_WPG:M" Return="check" />
```

However, I've heard that `PermissionEx` is better as it modifies ACLs instead of overwriting, (although the /E modifier here claims to do the same?) so I'd prefer to use that if possible. The only examples I can find for `PermissionEx` set permissions on the install dir and all subfolders - I don't want to do that.

How do I use `PermissionEx` to modify the permissions on a single folder *within* my install folder?

## UPDATE

Ok, here's what I've got so far - based on Yan's answer below and a bunch of other examples online

My folder structure....

```
<Fragment>
    <!-- Will default to C:\ if that is the main disk-->
    <Property Id="ROOTDRIVE"><![CDATA[C:\]]></Property>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <!-- Will reference to C:\inetpub-->
        <Directory Id="INETPUB" Name="Inetpub">
            <!-- Will reference to c:\Inetpub\wwwroot-->
            <Directory Id="WWWROOT" Name="wwwroot">
                <!-- Will reference to c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Demowebsite-->
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="DemoWebsite">
                    <Directory Id="CONTENT" Name="Content">         
                        <Directory Id="UPLOAD" Name="upload">
                        </Directory>         
                    </Directory>                                     
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

Yan's suggestion

```
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="UPLOAD">
      <Component Id="SetFolderPermissions" Guid="*">
        <CreateFolder>
           <util:PermissionEx GenericRead="yes" GenericExecute="yes" User="[SC_IUSR_USERNAME]" Domain="[SC_IUSR_DOMAIN]"/>
     <util:PermissionEx GenericRead="yes" GenericExecute="yes" GenericWrite="yes" Delete="yes" User="[SC_ASPNET_USERNAME]" Domain="[SC_ASPNET_DOMAIN]"/>
  </CreateFolder>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
```

This seems to do nothing. Permissions are not set for the IIS_IUSRS account. I've also tried this solution from [trycatchfail](http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/WiX-PermissionEx-problem-solved.aspx)

```
<Product>
    <!-- rest of product code removed for brevity -->
    <Property Id="WEBUSER" Value="Byah" />
    <Property Id="WEBDOMAIN" Value="Byah" />

    <CustomAction Id="SetWebuserIIS7" Return="check" Property="WEBUSER" Value="IIS_IUSRS" />
    <CustomAction Id="SetWebuserIIS6" Return="check" Property="WEBUSER" Value="IUSR_[ComputerName]" />
    <CustomAction Id="SetDomainIIS7" Return="check" Property="WEBDOMAIN" Value="" />
    <CustomAction Id="SetDomainIIS6" Return="check" Property="WEBDOMAIN" Value="[ComputerName]" />
</Product>

<Fragment>
  <DirectoryRef Id="UPLOAD">
  <Component Id="SetFolderPermissions" Guid="*">
    <CreateFolder>
      <util:PermissionEx User="NetworkService" GenericAll="yes" />
      <util:PermissionEx User="Administrators" GenericAll="yes" />
      <util:PermissionEx User="Users" GenericRead="yes" GenericExecute="yes"  />
      <util:PermissionEx User="[WEBUSER]" Domain="[WEBDOMAIN]"  GenericAll="yes" />
    </CreateFolder>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: I remember having this problem in the past as well. We did a lot of changes at that time but as far as I remember the Traverse="yes" attribute did the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a plain sample:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="WebsiteFolder">
   <Component DiskId="1" Id="DummyComponentForPermissionsWebsite" Guid="{GUID-GOES-HERE}">
      <CreateFolder>
         <util:PermissionEx GenericRead="yes" GenericExecute="yes" User="[SC_IUSR_USERNAME]" Domain="[SC_IUSR_DOMAIN]"/>
         <util:PermissionEx GenericRead="yes" GenericExecute="yes" GenericWrite="yes" Delete="yes" User="[SC_ASPNET_USERNAME]" Domain="[SC_ASPNET_DOMAIN]"/>
      </CreateFolder>
   </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

And here's a quick explanation:

- The sample above assumes there a `<Directory>` with `Id="WebsiteFolder"` defined somewhere
- The `<CreateFolder>` element is required because there's no other elements in this component. You can easily add `<util:PermissionEx>` elements to other components, which contain files, registry values, etc.
- The component above must be a part of a feature, of course
- The root WiX element must have `xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"` namespace referenced
- You must reference `WixUtilExtension` during compilation

Comment: Thanks Yan. This appears to run and set the permissions, but when I check the permissions through the security tab in file properties, I get this message `The permissions on upload are incorrectly ordered, which may cause some permissions to be ineffective` (upload is the name of my folder), any ideas? the only difference is I added `GenericWrite="yes"` for the first Permission node

Comment: Hmm, I definitely recall I've seen the warning like that, but I don't remember exactly what it was... Seems it has something to do with effective permissions. If I remember correctly, there must be a button "Reorder" somewhere inside Advanced Security area. Try to click that and see what's changed.

Comment: Reorder just seems to fix the permissions. Also the code above now sets these permissions on every folder within the install folder, not the upload folder alone. Just to be clear, my `DirectoryRef` is definitely the right folder, not the root or anything silly like that

Comment: What is the ```User="[SC_ASPNET_USERNAME]" Domain="[SC_ASPNET_DOMAIN]``` ?? Are they meant to be system default users? Or do we need to define them?

Comment: You need to define them. It was just an example of the project I've been working on.

Answer (score 1):

```
<CreateFolder>
    <Permission User="Users" GenericAll="yes" />
    <Permission User="Administrators" GenericAll="yes" />
</CreateFolder>
```

We can use PermissionEx instead Permission.

Its working for me.

Comment: One advantage of using "PermissionEx" is that it adds or modify the base permissions, so it is not necessary to replicate them in case you wanted to add an small tweak. "Permission" replace all permissions with you configuration.